# grepping an integer from line start bash

Tags: bash, grep

I have some homework on "*.txt*" handling.
I'm trying to grep lines by exact integer at their start:

```
grep -hw ^$grep_id ....
```

while grep_id is the exact integer I need.

But it gives me wrong result for example, if I have file".txt" like this:

```
2
21
30
```

If grepping by 2, I get:

```
2
21
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I don't know, why, but grep -hw ^2 ./1.txt worked correctly for me, returning 2, without 21. -w did it's job. Without -2 it gives 2 and 21

Comment: The command as given works for me, too. Have you checked that grep_id is exactly the number you want, with no trailing characters? If that doesn't pan out, I suggest checking the sanity of your `grep`/ coreutils installation -- for example are you sure that it's running proper grep and not a cutdown version like BusyBox grep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will only match the given `$grep_id` (using any non-numeric character as end-delimiter):

```
grep -hw "^$grep_id[^0-9]*" ...
```

Comment: thanks guy i had another problem with my input, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used:

```
grep "^${grep_id}\([^0-9]\|$\)"
```